# Show that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx |a_+\phi_n(x)|^2=(n+1)\hbar\omega$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, harmonic-oscillator

Consider that harmonic oscillator with
$$H\psi_n(x)=(n+\frac{1}{2})\hbar\omega$$ with $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx|\psi_n(x)|^2=1  .$$

We want to show that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx |a_+\psi_n(x)|^2=(n+1)h\omega \, .$$
where (for this edit i will use the operators my professor posted in his notes):
$a_{\pm}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{d}{dx}\pm im\omega x\right)$

I've made some progress from my original posting. But i got a slightly different result and it may have to do with how i'm manipulating the operators (this may be a symptom of a fundamental misunderstanding of operators, you tell me).
So,
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx |a_+\psi_n(x)|^2=\int dx(a_+\psi_n)^*(a_+\psi_n)$$
Here i let $(a_+\psi_n)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{d\psi}{dx}+im\omega x\psi_n\right)$ and $(a_+\psi_n)^*=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}\left(-\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{d\psi_n^*}{dx}-im\omega x\psi_n\right)$.

(Am i allowed to take the conjugate like that?)

Then (dropping the subscript for brevity), 
$$\int dx(a_+\psi_n)^*(a_+\psi_n)=\int dx \left[\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d\psi^*}{dx}\frac{d\psi}{dx}+\frac{mw^2x^2}{2}\psi^*\psi-\frac{\hbar\omega x}{2}\left(\frac{d\psi^*}{dx}\psi+\frac{d\psi}{dx}\psi^*\right)\right]$$
Here i break the integral into 3 parts to handle them separately. Applying integration by parts to the first term we have
$$\int dx \frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d\psi^*}{dx}\frac{d\psi}{dx}=\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left[\left(\frac{d\psi}{dx}\psi^*\right)_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\int dx \frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}\psi^*\right]=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\int dx \frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}\psi^*$$
(The wave function disappears at the integration limits leaving the integral above.)

For the second term we observe that:
$$\frac{mw^2x^2}{2}\psi^*\psi=V(x)\psi^*\psi$$
For that last term we observe that:
$$-\int dx \frac{\hbar\omega x}{2}\left(\frac{d\psi^*}{dx}\psi+\frac{d\psi}{dx}\psi^*\right)= -\frac{\hbar\omega}{2}\int x \frac{d}{dx}(\psi^*\psi)dx=-\frac{\hbar\omega}{2}\int \frac{dx}{dx}|\psi|^2dx=-\frac{\hbar\omega}{2}$$
Putting the parts back together:
$$\int dx \left[\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}\psi^*+\psi^*V(x)\psi\right] -\frac{\hbar\omega}{2}$$

Here we observe that:
$$\int dx \left[\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}\psi^*+V(x)\psi^*\psi\right]-\frac{\hbar\omega}{2}=\int\psi_n^*H\psi_n dx -\frac{\hbar\omega}{2}$$

Now here i get a bit sketchy...

We are given that $H\psi_n=(n+\frac{1}{2})\hbar\omega$.

I can't justify this next step:
$$\int\psi_n^*H\psi_n dx -\frac{\hbar\omega}{2}=(n+\frac{1}{2})\hbar\omega-\frac{\hbar\omega}{2}=n\hbar\omega$$
$\Large{?????????????}$

So it seems like i'm really close to the proof. But if that last step IS justifiable then i have proven that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx |a_+\phi_n(x)|^2=n\hbar\omega$ not the intended $(n+1)\hbar\omega$.

So it seems that there is either an issue with my professors definition of the "a" operator; i.e. it should be $a_{\pm}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{d}{dx}\mp im\omega x\right)$. NOTE: When i use this definition i DO get the correct answer. OR there is an issue with my conjugation of the operator.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. To keep the quality of posts high, we have specific rules about questions asking for help on calculations. In short: the post must identify a specific conceptual issue and ask about that. As written, this post will probably be closed as a violation of the homework policy. However, if you could perhaps expand on the part where you say *"...but I got lost..."* by explaining *why* you got lost, then we might have something more suitable.

Comment: Is the first line supposed to be $H\psi_n = (n + (1/2))\hbar \omega \psi_n$?

Comment: The expression you're trying to prove doesn't look right dimensionally

Comment: @DanielSank- Yes. I edited it. I will show some of my work when i get home later today.

Comment: I have reworked this post, hopefully it is up to snuff and the hold can be released.  I made some progress on my own but there's some issues either with my definition of the operator or my handling of the operators. I've discussed this in the post.

Comment: I figured it out. And i can justify the last step.  Should i delete this post or edit it so others can see the solution?